# How do I load a theme that I have downloaded onto emacs?

Tags: emacs, themes

I have the .el file downloaded on my drive but I can't figure out how to load it into emacs. I am a very big noob at emacs, just started today and am just trying to change the theme. How do I do it? A step by step process would be appreciated. I have looked on the internet on how to do it but the documentation people give is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to load the file when you start emacs: from the command line, type `emacs -l /path/to/theme.el`  where you will have to provide the path (absolute or relative) to the file that you downloaded.

If you want to make this change permanent, then you can modify your initialization file (the `.emacs` file in your home directory usually, although that depends on what OS you are running; or equivalently `$HOME/.emacs.d/init.el`). Add the following line at the end:

```
 (load-file "/path/to/theme.el")
```

again replacing the path with whatever is appropriate in your case (but make sure it's an absolute path, so it can be found no matter where you start your emacs from).

There are other ways, but these two are enough for now: you can learn about the rest later.

Comment: so if I want to do the permanent method I would just put that at the very end of the file then save right? Would the change happen instantly or would I have to restart emacs?

Comment: The initialization file is only read when emacs is first started, so you would have to restart emacs.

Comment: @Low_level_dir @Nick You don't need to restart.  You can use `M-x eval-buffer`, or position your cursor at the end of the `load-theme` line and use `C-x C-e` (which calls `eval-last-sexp`) to evaluate the expression and load your theme immediately.

Comment: Yes, I know: look at the last sentence in my answer. I am trying not to overwhelm the OP, a "very big noob at emacs".